# how to set the font size in react native pell rich editor++++

Tags: react-native, editor

I am using the react native pell rich editor for my react native app.But unable to set the font size. anybody please help me to set the font size for the text

Answer (score 0):

I am able to give multiple font styles, but not Font-family, you may take reference from below my code.

```
<RichEditor
        ref={richText}
        initialFocus={false}
        initialHeight={40}
        editorStyle={{
          color: ColorConstant.MAIN_DARK,
          contentCSSText: 'font-size: 42px;',
          
        }}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        placeholder="add description*"
        //editorInitializedCallback={() => this.onEditorInitialized()}
        // onChange={descriptionText => {
        //   console.log('descriptionText:', descriptionText);
        // }}
        onChange={text => {
          setEventDescription(text);
        }}
      />
```